# What can we tell from a contract's public address?

Tags: contract-development, blockchain, privacy

This is asked differently around but I haven't found an explanation as direct as I wanted to.

I've read that all state variables in a contract are publicly visible ([solidity docs](https://solidity.readthedocs.io/en/develop/common-patterns.html#restricting-access)). It's stated there: "Note that you can never restrict any human or computer from reading the content of your transactions or your contract’s state".

I understand it conceptually but I wonder what steps would be required in order to get the state variables from a contract. Specifically, I've deployed a contract to address `0x8325ba5B0A67745FC6F21DC9A9Cb43f5E8d9c5Df` in the Rinkeby test chain. What are the steps required for someone to see the state of my contract? And follow-up, can someone see the functions that contract implements?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [eth_getStorageAt](https://github.com/ethereum/wiki/wiki/JSON-RPC#eth_getstorageat) rpc method (or web3 function) to get the value at a particular position in storage. In web3 this would look like

```
web3.eth.getStorageAt("0x8325ba5B0A67745FC6F21DC9A9Cb43f5E8d9c5Df", my_storage_position, "latest")
```

where `my_storage_position` is the storage slot of the variable you want (they just increase sequentially by order of declaration).

For example, if your contract starts like this:

```
contract MyContract {

    address owner;
    uint balance;
    bytes32 data

    ....
}
```

you would use

```
eth.getStorageAt(my_address, 0, "latest")
```

for `owner`
, `1` for `balance`, `2` for `data`, etc.

Strings and arrays are a bit trickier. The data actually stored in the normal spot `p` is the length of the string, and the real string starts at `keccak256(p)`. See [the docs](http://solidity.readthedocs.io/en/develop/miscellaneous.html#layout-of-state-variables-in-storage) for details.

While you cannot tell what the names of functions are, the bytecode is publicly visible, and a determined person could definitely figure out what exactly the contract does. The bytecode can be translated into slightly more readable assembly with tools like https://etherscan.io/opcode-tool.

Comment: Running `web3.eth.getStorageAt("0x8325ba5B0A67745FC6F21DC9A9Cb43f5E8d9c5Df", my_storage_position, "latest")` in my geth console connected to Rinkeby returns `ReferenceError: 'my_storage_position' is not defined`. I'm probably missing something but I didn't quite understand how you'd see, say, and address I have stored in the contract. Also, what would be the steps to convert the bytecode to intelligible information regarding the functioning of the contract? Thanks!

Comment: You're supposed to replace `my_storage_position` with a number, indicating which storage position you want to view

Comment: Awesome, that works now! Sorry to insist but two more things: if I store a string, say "mcansado" in a contract and I run that command, what should I get back (assuming it's the only thing stored in the contract)? And how could I translate that to "mcansado" (assuming it'll return some hex value). And I'm still curious regarding the second part of my comment above: what would be the steps to convert the bytecode to intelligible information regarding the functioning of the contract?

Comment: Updated to provide a bit more clarity